# If f is integrable and it's fourier transform is integrable too , then $f$ and $\hat{f}$ are $L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

Proposition i find in a course : "If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$  is integrable and it's fourier transform is integrable too , then $f$ and $\hat{f}$ are $L^1$ ".

I can't really figure out why it's so trivial.
I can't really manage to find out why convergence of $f$ would implie absolute convergence on $\mathbb{R}$..

Comment: Integrable often already means $L^1$. Can you be more specific about the assumptions on $f$ and $\hat{f}$ ?

Comment: There are none , it's the full proposition , the only information is f is a $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ function (eventually , i can add $\hat{f}$ refers to the fourier transform of f)

Comment: Then what does 'integrable' mean?

Comment: Doesn't integrable means $\int{f}$ < $\infty$ if the integral exists to the Lebesgue sense ? (This is not a course of integration , so in that course there are no definition of the word "integrable", it's left to the reader comprehension)

Comment: Usually it means a measurable function which positive and negative parts have a finite  integral.

Comment: Thanks , it helped me figure it out.

Comment: this cannot be a "proposition": it is just the **definition** of being a $L^1$ function